# Xcode 13 default SwiftUI file refuses to start previews

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, xcode13

I have just created a SwiftUI view file, and it is refusing to render previews. I have not changed anything to the default file, here are the contents as proof :

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And when I try to start previews, I get this error :
`Cannot preview in this file -- Message send failure for send previewInstances message to agent`
and clicking `diagnostics` shows this :

```
MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for send previewInstances message to agent

==================================

|  RemoteHumanReadableError
|  
|  LoadingError: failed to load library at path "/Users/ambrosine/Library/Containers/C62869A9-4B70-4E37-8214-47A4E1A1AB38/Data/ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib": Optional(dlopen(/Users/ambrosine/Library/Containers/C62869A9-4B70-4E37-8214-47A4E1A1AB38/Data/ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/ambrosine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Layer_Cake-arsciremknllubbhasphthxgplvu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Layer Cake (macOS)/Products/Debug/ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/ambrosine/Library/Containers/C62869A9-4B70-4E37-8214-47A4E1A1AB38/Data/ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib' (code signature in <B85C00C0-8585-36D2-A859-1B19877BB41F> '/Users/ambrosine/Library/Containers/C62869A9-4B70-4E37-8214-47A4E1A1AB38/Data/ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)))
```

Being fairly new I don't really understand the error, seems to have something to do with code signing but I'm not entirely sure what and how to fix it.

I should also mentioned that the app builds and works without any errors, and that I have tried cleaning the build folder, restarting XCode, and restarting my Mac.

Comment: Deleting 'DerivedData' folder might help.

Comment: In the project file, go to the target > Signing & Capabilities, then see what's in the `team` drop down, you may need to go through `add an account...`

Comment: @cora Did not work, but I did make a shortcut to try that quickly next time something breaks

Comment: @acinglio Thank you ! It worked. I disabled and re-enabled `Automatically manage signing` and it fixed the problem. Could you please make your response an "Answer" so I can mark the question as solved and it is easier for other people to find this post in the future ?